# Euler X Support in Google Vision API

Tags: android, face-detection, vision, euler-angles

Does anybody know if Google plans to add Euler X support for their Vision API in the future?  Or if there is a workaround to find it for now?

It appears they had it on media.FaceDetector (an earlier class) and would be very useful for a project I'm working on.

Answer (score 0):

We are considering this for a future release, but do not have a release date to announce at this time.

You might try detecting the facial landmarks, and see if the relative positions of the landmarks gives you enough of a hint as to Euler X.

Comment: Thanks for the update!  The only method I've found that works reasonably well is by measuring the vertical offset of the lines connecting the eyes and ears.  Unfortunately the ears are not easily detected (appears to be almost undetectable at Euler Y around zero).  All of the other landmarks have very little relative motion on head up/head down so it is difficult to determine angle from them.  Do you have a specific set of landmarks you would recommend?

Comment: I haven't looked at this closely.  One thing that you might try would be to increase the resolution on the images that you are using, since higher resolution images have more detail -- the ears may be more easily detected that way.  Note that the examples tended to use lower resolution images since detection tends to be faster that way (choice of resolution is a speed / accuracy trade-off).  Another thing to try would be using "accurate" mode, which can detect faces at a wider range of angles.